# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column when I created a new column using a condition with a UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I created a data frame based on a text summary to find the document frequency (DF) and inverse document frequency (IDF).

[image: the data frame with cleaned corpus with token extracted from it and a doc id]

Here are the columns with document frequency and the word tokens -

[image: doc frequency with word tokens]

However, when I try to calculate the IDF for each row in the dataframe using a user-defined function, I get the error mentioned.

[image: exception]

Here's the code for the udf (that iterates over each row) and the function(that calculates the IDF)

[image: user-defined fucntion]

[image: function to calculate idf]

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to write a function to calculate IDF yourself, as it is already implemented in spark-mllib, see:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#tf-idf

Also, without seeing how the calcIDF function is defined, we cannot provide much help over the NotSerializableException.

Comment: I added the function to calculate IDF